# Resetting The Windows 8 Music App Database

Tags: windows-8, music, modern-ui

The Windows 8 Music App (XboX Music is not available in my country, and this is the alternative) downloads album art by default. I didn't want the app to show vulgar pictures, so I have disabled the function. The problem is that it has already downloaded a few pictures which I find inappropriate. I'd like to remove those.

Luckily, it seems like the pictures were not embedded to the MP3 files. I believe the Music App handles meta-data in a way similar to Windows Media Player, which creates a dedicated database.

How do I reset the database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows 8 Music holds its albums in the Windows 8 Music Library. Here's what I had to do to reset my Music Library

- Open Explorer
- Click on 'Libraries'
- Right click on 'Music'
- Click on each Library location and Remove
- Click OK

After you've done this you need to uninstall and reinstall the music app

- Bring up the start screen
- Right click on the music app, and click 'Uninstall' from the app bar
- Go into the store
- Search for 'Music'
- Reinstall the Music app

Answer (score 0):

Clear the Windows Media Player database cache files . To do this, follow these steps:

a. Click Start , click Run , type %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft , and then click OK.

b. Select the Media Player folder , and then click Delete on the File menu.

c. Restart Windows Media Player .

Give this a go.  Taken from: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-pictures/delete-or-re-locate-media-player-cache/1b9817c7-7b83-405d-a1b7-29c4ed915fed?msgId=4fa98343-caef-4845-99cd-fcb7dd35100a

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. Note that my question regards the Windows 8 Music App, not Windows Media Player.